# Campagnolo Zonda Ratchet sound

Tags: cassette, freewheel, rear-wheel, freehub

I bought a Campagnolo Zonda C17 recently and noticed how quiet the ratcheting noise was. My friend owns a pair of Zondas but his one is really loud. why is mine silent? i use a 15 cassette.

Comment: I suppose yours has a quieter freehub.

Comment: What is a 15 cassette?

Comment: Some are loud, some are quiet.  There's really no rhyme nor reason for it.  The clicks do get somewhat quieter with lubrication and with age though.

Comment: Another possibility is that you and/or your friend have fake wheels. This shouldn't be the case if you bought the wheels from reputable dealers, but if you bought them on the internet, its possible (though I don't know if it is common with this wheelset).

Answer (score 1):

New freehubs are quieter, because they have a thicker layer of grease between contact surfaces in the freewheel. The grease will eventually be pushed away from the surfaces, and the hub will develop the trademark sound in few thousand kilometers.

Comment: My old RSX hub is almost silent.... I can't hear it coasting while riding even on a quiet empty road.

Comment: I believe the question was about Campagnolo hubs, specifically Zonda. They are loud.